# Performing Raster Calculation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

This is my formal:

```
("Standort_ger_fre_mosaic" ^ 0.4) *
("Habitattradition_raster_rec.tif" ^ 0.3) * 
("Vollständigkeit_rec.tif" ^ 0.1) * 
("Vorkommen_ungestörter_Lebensräume_rec.tif" ^ 0.1) * 
("Vorkommen_von_Arten_dynamischer_Lebensräume_rec.tif"^ 0.1)
```

I would like to charge the pixels of the above-mentioned layers together.
As a final product,[image] I would like to have a file that has different values ​​for each pixel.
When I do the computation, my final product has only one value in each pixel. This is equal to 0

I am working with ArcMap 10.6

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "^", use the "Power" function as follows:

```
(Power("Standort_ger_fre_mosaic",0.4)) *
(Power("Habitattradition_raster_rec.tif",0.3)) *
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a rounding issue. Please try converting your image values to float before the exponent. Also I suggest to use Power.

```
Power(Float("Standort_ger_fre_mosaic"),0.4) ) *
Power(Float("Habitattradition_raster_rec.tif"),0.3) ...
```

Comment: I think the Power function alone does the trick. I tried Power("image",0.4) with an uint8 image and it worked just fine